# Installing Ubuntu via SD card

Tags: system-installation, sd-card

I want to put Ubuntu, but I do not have USB-stick.
Tell me, is it possible to install Ubuntu with SD-card?

Comment: If your computer can boot from an SD card, you can use it to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I tried to boot from the SD card, but I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very easily... bring in a memory-card-reader... Plug it in with windows/Linux and try some software on windows like Universsal Usb creator or on Ubuntu there is something called Startup disk creator.

Universal USB link :

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/